Basis for the space of alternating polynomial

Here "antisymmetric" means alternating. I am wondering how these objects $a_{\lambda}$ actually form a basis for the space of antisymmetric polynomial. If anyone could provide a proof I would be greatful.
Thanks.

Please don't use images.
